# Loop through list tuples and add if there is no match

Tags: c#, list, loops, tuples

i am writing a game server in C#,every time someone sends the login message with his username i add him to a list of tuples with ID,IPENDPOINT,USERNAME.
I want to check if the client doesn't have same username as an already connected client,so i tried to loop through the list and get list.Item3 'which is username' and use String.Equals(list.Item3, username) to check if the username exists.
My problem is when i loop,my code compares to only the first tuple in the list,if it was true then send a error message,if not then send accept message and when the list has +1 client it only compares to the first also and accept even if the tuple number 2 or 3... has that username.
i tried many ways,this is the last code i tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < clientsInfoList.Count; i++)
{
    bool isUsed;
    if (String.Equals(clientsInfoList[i].Item3, Username))
    {
        isUsed = true;
    }

    if (isUsed)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Username is already used!");
        udpServer.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("REFUSED"), Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount("REFUSED"), remoteEP);
        break;
    }            
    else if(!isUsed)
    {
        clientsInfoList.Add(new Tuple<int, IPEndPoint, string>(id, remoteEP, Username));
        Console.WriteLine("Username has been added to the list :)");
        udpServer.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ACCEPTED"), Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount("ACCEPTED"), remoteEP);                    
    }
}
```

i tried many other ways but i couldn't achieve the verification.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put everything in a loop. Why? You should use the loop only to check whether the username is taken or not and send your messages outside of it.

First of all you'd like to force your loop to work only as long as  it should. You can do it by declaring `isUsed` before it and adding it to the condition. Then, in the loop, you only check whether the name is taken and change the value of your variable. The loop will either iterate through all the clients or end when it encounters the first name that matches your condition. When the loop is over, you should decide which command you send basing on the results.

```
bool isUsed = false;
for (int i = 0; i < clientsInfoList.Count && !isUsed; i++)
{
   isUsed = String.Equals(clientsInfoList[i].Item3, Username);
}

if (isUsed)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Username is already used!");
   udpServer.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("REFUSED"), Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount("REFUSED"), remoteEP);
}
else
{
   clientsInfoList.Add(new Tuple<int, IPEndPoint, string>(id, remoteEP, Username));
   Console.WriteLine("Username has been added to the list :)");
   udpServer.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ACCEPTED"), Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount("ACCEPTED"), remoteEP);

}
```

Comment: i tried you solution but i get : Use of unassigned local variable 'isUsed'

Comment: I changed `bool isUsed` to `bool isUsed = false;`. Try it and tell me if it worked.

Comment: `isUsed` will still only tell if the *last* item in the `List<>` uses that name. Your loop continues no matter what username it sees.

Comment: No it doesn't. When it finds a name that is equal to `Username` it sets `isUsed` to true. That makes the condition `i < clientsInfoList.Count && !isUsed` false and the loop stops.

Comment: Thank you man,it worked :D i tried it with 4 clients connected who tries to use already connected username,and it worked :D

Comment: You are right, sorry. I did not read the `for` loop carefully enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
var isUsed = clientsInfoList.Any(info => info.Item3 == Username);
if (isUsed)
{
  // ...
}
else
{
  // ...
}
```

I assume both `Item3` (the `T3` of `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`) and `Username` have *compile-time* type `string`.

Comment: someone already found a solution,but i'll give it a try :)
thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you put the entire logic in the for loop ? Place only the below code inside for loop.

```
            bool isUsed;
            if (String.Equals(clientsInfoList[i].Item3, Username))
            {
                isUsed = true;
            }
```

It will now verify all elements in the tuple and perform the remaining logic.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this the wrong way entirely, first thing I would do if I was you, would be to get rid of the Tuples, create a class which contains the 3 properties that you need.

Also in such circumstances try to use a HashSet instead of a list, they're better optimized and will help your game run faster if you have a large collection of clients.

The cleanest way to achieve what you're asking is by using LINQ, here's how I would rewrite the code that you've written above.

```
public class Game 
{
    public Game()
    {
        this.Clients = new HashSet<Clients>(); 
    }

    public HashSet<Client> Clients { get; set;}

    public void OnClientConnect(Client newClient)
    {
        // Are there any clients with the username that the newUser is attempting to use?
        bool usernameIsFree = this.Clients.Any(clients => clients.UserName == newClient.UserName);

        if (usernameIsFree)
        {
            this.Clients.Add(newClient);
            Console.WriteLine("Username has been added to the list :)");
            // UDP stuff here...
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Username is already used!");
        // UDP stuff here   
    }
}
public class Client 
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public IPEndPoint IPEndPoint { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion and code,am trying to keep it simple for me so i can then store some data in sqlite db later,and since this will be checked only when client connect's,performance is not really required now,but actually i'll try to work with your code ;)
Thanks again :)